# Which overridden method of Activity runs when click on notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I have `MainActivity` which I want to open when user clicks on a notification.

My code is below.

`Manifest.xml`:

```
 <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"></activity>
```

Notification code:

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I want to know:

- Which overridden method is called when my app is closed and I click on a notification?
- Which overridden method is called when my app is running and I click on a notification?

Answer (score 0):

Good Monday Morning!

It's actually a bit more complex: when your notification is clicked, the pending `Intent` you created is executed and, as a result, the activity which was assigned in your notification (in your case the `MainActivity`)

So the activity starts as a normal activity and if you need to pass some parameters, just add extra to the `Intent` before transforming it in a `Pending Intent`

Comment: But I think this is not what you're looking for: I thought you wanted to understand how it works once the user click it... Then my answer is correct, else if you want to know how to trigger this notification you just wrote look at @Amit answer

Comment: amit answer might correct but in different sense . he didn't read my question properly here i am copy pasting it again you might help better



i want to know that

which overridden method called when my app is closed and i click on notification ?

which overridden method called when my app is running and i click on notification ?

Comment: When you click a notification the intent starts... So it starts the activity and the normal workflow on the activity: onCreate, onStart, onResume and so on

Comment: its mean no matter your activity is running on foreground or background always oncreate will run ?

Comment: Ahhhhhh, it's depending on the flag of the `Pending Intent`, but `onResume`is called every time

Answer (score 0):

**OnMessage** will always get called whenever notification came to mobile, even if app is closed or running or in background.

```
protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
// Your code here 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Amit, I guess you're right but I understood the question totally differently.

Comment: Do activity really have this method ? can't see it

Comment: No that the GCM receiver which have that... https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService What are you trying to do Server to Phone notification or just local notifications?

Comment: its server to phone but the issue is not that . i am successfully sending notification from 

  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {}

but i want to know when i click on notification which method of main activity will run when app is running or app is in background